# The class call executes only part of the code, without giving an error

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning python, now I'm learning to work with the tkinter module and object-oriented programming.  I'm trying to write a program that creates a window to work in it. To do this, I wrote the Page class as a template. In order for the window to have a background, I used Canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
import PIL
hello_text = 'some text'

start_page_titel = 'some text'

class Page:
    def __init__(self, title_of, g_x, g_y):
        self.title_of = title_of
        self.g_x = g_x
        self.g_y = g_y
    
    
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.win_bg = PhotoImage(file = 'some pic.png')
       
        self.window.title(title_of)
        self.window.geometry(f'{g_x}x{g_y}+300+300')
        self.window.resizable(False, False)
        
        self.canv_win = tk.Canvas(self.window, width = g_x, height = g_y)
        
        self.canv_win.create_image(0, 0, image = self.win_bg, anchor = 'nw' )
    
    
    def text_for(self, txt_x, txt_y, some_text):
        self.canv_win.create_text(txt_x, txt_y, text = some_text, fill = 'white')
        
    
    def start(self):
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    
    def stop(self):
        self.window.destroy()

start_page = Page(start_page_titel, 1024, 655)
start_page.text_for(350,50, hello_text)    
start_page.start()
```

When creating an instance of the class, a window appears with the title, but with an empty background and no text.
At the same time, the console does not issue errors. Tell me where in the description of the class method I could have made a mistake.

Comment: You forget to call any layout function on the canvas, so it is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Re-edit: add new screenshot.

You are missing `pack` or `grid` or `place`.

Change white to blue, so you can see text.

```
self.canv_win = tk.Canvas(self.window, width = g_x, height = g_y)
self.canv_win.pack() # add this one
```

Change coordinate of x value to 150.

```
start_page.text_for(150, ..., ....
```

Screenshot:

[image]